# Adding a legend to a MatrixPlot

Tags: graphics, legending

I have produced this MatrixPlot:

[image]

Rows refer to countries and columns to ranks. Row 1 refers to Norway with many 1 ranks, row 15 to Greece with many 15 ranks. Other countries are inbetween.

I would like to add a "Legend" to this plot, i.e. the string "Norway" should align (on the right side) with the first row etc.

I have no idea how to accomplish this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you basically want `Ticks` with names instead of numbers?

Comment: Exactly! Left numbers, bottom numbers, right countries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifying `FrameTicks` adds a *"legend"* to `MatrixPlot`'s row:

```
legend = {"Hello", "How are you?", "Good Bye"};
MatrixPlot[{{1, 2, 1}, {3, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {
    {True (* Left *), 
     Thread[{Range@Length@legend, legend}](* Right *)}, 
    {True (* Bottom *), False (* Top *)}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, beautiful and exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)